# Authorization issue when running VSCODE

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have instaled the Ubunto 22.04 in a Google instance and have also instaled VSCODE using SNAP.

I had no problem with instalation, but when I try to open VSCODE I'm receiving this error :

```
Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified
[1301:1220/185049.512682:ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(240)] Missing X server or $DISPLAY
[1301:1220/185049.512752:ERROR:env.cc(255)] The platform failed to initialize.  Exiting.
```

I'll thank for some guidance of how to fix this.

Tks.

Comment: You need a desktop to run vscode.  You should install vscode on your personal system and then set up a ssh private key.

Comment: Additional information : If I run CODE using SUDO (sudo code --no-sandbox --user-data-dir="~/.vscode-root") it work fine, so this issue is a mater of lack of authority. So How can I identify where this authority is missing.?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I cannot add a comment so have to add this as an answer:
But I am getting the exact same problem.

The issue does not appear to be about permission though. I am able to run vscode from a command line just fine as my normal user. But when I switch to root and try to do the same that is when I get this error.

```
Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified

[4827:0115/081942.759486:ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(240)] Missing X server or $DISPLAY
[4827:0115/081942.759530:ERROR:env.cc(255)] The platform failed to initialize.  Exiting.
The futex facility returned an unexpected error code.
zsh: IOT instruction  code-oss
```

I am assuming it has something to do with a missing step in the .bashrc or .zshrc setup. But I tried setting the DISPLAY env to match that of my normal user and it didnt help.